# Is there a systematic way to determine the irreducible representations of a finite group?

Tags: representation-theory

I was reading through fulton and harris's book on representation theory. I'm in the middle of chapter 3 and noticed their approach to finding irreducible representations of groups is pretty exploratory. I see no reason to believe the methods employed should always work.

So, I was wondering is there an efficient method to find all the irreducible representations of a given finite group?

Comment: What's that approach? Please share a link or clearly write where you ask while you mention equations from book/text etc. Everybody does not have the book in hand

Comment: I don't know about the irr. representations but [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365096/does-anyone-know-the-burnside-matrices) is a way of getting the character table.

Comment: @ aQuestion: I don't think that will be very helpful. They worked out the cases of the symmetric group of order 3,4,5, which have few conjugacy classes. They usually start off by noting the trivial, alternating, and standard representations are irreducible (the fact that this is true for the last of these appearsto be just luck) and use facts like the orthogonality of the character table to determine what the final few classes are.

Comment: "Systematic" and "efficient" don't necessarily mean the same thing. A thing you might want from "systematic" is a method you can apply to understand a large class of related groups at once. Such methods are known for families of groups such as the symmetric groups $S_n$ and the general linear groups $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, but the answers get pretty complicated and it's quite nontrivial to describe them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that efficient algorithms to find the irreducible representations of a finite group do exist, but they are beyond the scope of a first course in representation theory.  See the following question on Math Overflow:

[How to compute all irreducible representations of a finite group ? (how GAP is doing this?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111379/how-to-compute-all-irreducible-representations-of-a-finite-group-how-gap-is-d)